# Change Authorization for Users on React/Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Using React and Firebase I have a small page where users can vote on polls.

I am trying to achieve that all polls (saved on Firebase Database) can be seen by all users (registered via Firebase Authentication).

At the moment only users that are manually assigned to the poll in the database can see the poll on their Dashboard.

Below is the Dashboard.js file. Can anyone help me to figure out what I have to change to authorize all users to see all polls automatically?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { firebaseApp } from '../utils/firebase';
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import Loading from './Loading';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            dialogOpen: false,
            loading: true,
            polls: [] //items like { id: 34324, title: 'sdf'}
        };

        this.poll2Delete = '';
        this.poll2DeleteTitle = ''

        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        //const uid = getLocalUserId();

        firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) { //this can get called after componentWillUnmount, make sure its there to avoid errors

                const uid = user.uid;

                this.userPollsRef = firebaseApp.database().ref(`user-polls/${uid}`);

                //check if user has no polls to quit loading indicator
                this.userPollsRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
                    if (!snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                        if (this.mounted) {
                            this.setState({ loading: false });
                        }
                    }
                });

                this.userPollsRef.on('child_added', ((newPollIdSnapshot) => {
                    const pollId = newPollIdSnapshot.key;

                    firebaseApp.database().ref(`polls/${pollId}/title`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
                        const title = snapshot.val();

                        const polls = this.state.polls;
                        polls.push({ title: title, id: pollId })

                        if (this.mounted) {
                            this.setState({
                                polls: polls,
                                loading: false
                            });
                        }
                    });

                })).bind(this);

                this.userPollsRef.on('child_removed', ((removedPollIdSnapshot) => {
                    const pollId = removedPollIdSnapshot.key;
                    const polls = this.state.polls.filter(poll => poll.id !== pollId);

                    if (this.mounted) {
                        this.setState({
                            polls: polls
                        });
                    }

                })).bind(this);
            }
        });

        this.mounted = true; //the callbacks above can be called after componentWillUnmount(), to avoid errors, check
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.userPollsRef.off();
        this.mounted = false;
    }

    handleOpen(pollId) {
        this.setState({ dialogOpen: true });
        this.poll2Delete = pollId;
        this.poll2DeleteTitle = this.state.polls.find(poll => poll.id === this.poll2Delete).title;
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({ dialogOpen: false });
    }

    handleDelete() {
        // updating to null deletes
        const updates = {};
        updates[`/polls/${this.poll2Delete}`] = null;
        updates[`/user-polls/${firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid}/${this.poll2Delete}`] = null;

        firebaseApp.database().ref().update(updates);

        this.setState({ dialogOpen: false });
    }

    render() {

        const actions = [
            <FlatButton
                label="Cancel"
                primary={false}
                onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
                />,
            <FlatButton
                label="Delete"
                primary={true}
                onTouchTap={this.handleDelete}
                />,
        ];

        let pollsUIs = this.state.polls.map((poll) => {
            return (
                <div key={poll.id} >

                    <IconButton
                        iconClassName="fa fa-trash"
                        />
                    <Link to={`/polls/poll/${poll.id}`}>
                        <FlatButton
                            label={poll.title}
                            style={{ textAlign: 'left', width: '50%' }}
                            />
                    </Link>
                    <Divider />

                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-12 text-xs-center">

                    <Helmet title="Dashboard" />

                    <Paper>

                        <br />
                        <h2> Current Polls </h2>
                        <br />

                        <Dialog
                            actions={actions}
                            modal={false}
                            open={this.state.dialogOpen}
                            onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                            >
                            Delete "{this.poll2DeleteTitle}"?
                    </Dialog>

                        <br /><br />

                        {pollsUIs}

                        <Loading loading={this.state.loading} />

                        <br /><br />
                    </Paper>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not used to firebase, but and I think you have to remove uid from the paramater in order to get all the results from firebase.

```
this.userPollsRef = firebaseApp.database().ref(`user-polls/${uid}`)
```

to like this

```
this.userPollsRef = firebaseApp.database().ref(`user-polls`)
```